# Integration of Tomcat 7 with IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, tomcat7, isapi

After following all the steps related to integration of tomcat7 and IIS7 i am getting below error.Any idea what might be the cause?First time when I did all the steps as mentioned in tutorial my site was coming up then suddenly it stop coming up.Again i removed my site from IIS and followed the steps but then every time below error is coming:-

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. Detailed Error Information
Module IsapiFilterModule 
Notification AuthenticateRequest 
Handler StaticFile
Error Code 0x80070001 
Physical Path D:\New\IISROOT 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous 
Failed Request Tracing Log Directory D:\New\Tomcat\logs

I have checked the logs but trace log is not created as well as isapi_redirect.logs

I have followed the below steps:

1.created the two files workers.properties and uriworkermap.properties in tomcat\conf

-In workers.properties i added the below information

worker.list=mysite worker.mysite.host=localhost worker.mysite.port=8009 worker.mysite.type=ajp13

-In uriworkermap.properties i added the below information

/mysite/*=mysiteworker

2.Created isapi-rediect.properties in Tomcat\bin

extension_uri=/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll log_file=D:\DLNew\Tomcat\logs\isapi_redirect.log log_level=debug worker_file=C:\Tomcat\conf\workers.properties worker_mount_file=c:\Tomcat\conf\uriworkermap.properties

3.Add ISAPI Filter

In AddIsapi Filter dialog box i have given filtername as jakarta and Executable path as c:\Tomcat\bin\isapi\isapi-redirect.dll

2.Add Virtual Directory

In Add VirtualDirectory Dialog box i have given Alias as jakarta and PhysicalPath as c:\Tomcat\bin\isapi

3.selected jakarta virtual directory in connections panel -Double-click the 'Handler Mappings' icon in 'Features View'. -Click the 'Edit Feature Permissions' link in the 'Actions' panel. -Ensure that the 'Execute' option is selected.

4.Register the ISAPI Extension In ISAPI OR CGI restriction Dialog box i have given ISAPI or CGI path as c:\Tomcat\bin\isapi\isapi-redirect.dll and description as jakarta and i enabled the checkbox of allow extension path to execute

I am able to access the application through Tomcat by using the url as:http://localhost:80/mysite

But application is not comming up through IIS: i am getting below exception in browser

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. Detailed Error Information Module IsapiFilterModule Notification AuthenticateRequest Handler StaticFile Error Code 0x80070001 Physical Path D:\New\IISROOT Logon Method Anonymous Logon User Anonymous Failed Request Tracing Log Directory c:Tomcat\logs

Comment: This questions should be posted to serverfault.com. Which tutorial and which steps? You must start from http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: run command 'tasklist /m isapi*' and see if the redirect is registered.